# Graphic Problems after installation of 12.04

Tags: bootloader

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows XP. The problem is that I cannot see the bootloader menu to choose XP anymore. My monitor shows the the message: *Optimal Mode 1440x990 60Hz*. After a while Ubuntu starts and I can see the Unity screen.

I have an onBoard Graffic: `NVIDIA Cooporation C61 [Geforce 6100 nForce 405] (rev a2)`

How can I fix that problem?

Comment: See this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/178614/cant-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu/178633#178633 or this http://askubuntu.com/questions/153040/frequency-out-of-range-please-change-display-mode

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the bootloader resolution is set too high, which your monitor cannot handle. To change it, boot into Ubuntu.

Open your terminal and type

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

find the line

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

remove the # before the line GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

save, then type in terminal

```
sudo update-grub
```

now reboot and see