# Can't use LXLE except through Live CD

Tags: lubuntu, resolution

I'm really new to Linux so I apologize in advance for my generalized ignorance on the subject. (I apologize for my English as well)
Recently, after Microsoft stopped to provide support to Windows XP, I decided to install LXLE 12.04 32-bit on an old PC I own.

The installation went well and I can use LXLE through the Live CD without any issues (actually at this very moment I'm writing this post from there). The problem arises when I take out the CD and try to boot from the hard drive - then the screen turns black and I get the following message - "Attention - Out of range - H: 92.6 KHZ - V: 58.3 HZ"
I looked for solutions online and it seems it's a screen resolution problem, but I can't really see what to do to fix it. I tried reinstalling but that doesn't help either.

On the back of my monitor there are some indications which I think are related to the issue and that I'm copying here: "Power rating: 100-240V - 50/60 HZ  1.5 A"
If more information about the computer is needed in order to help me, please tell me so and I'll add it to the post.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try booting from hard drive and wait a few minutes. Ubuntu should boot after some time. If this happens, follow the answer  http://askubuntu.com/questions/178614/cant-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu to fix GRUB.

Comment: It worked perfectly and now the GRUB menu appears right after BIOS. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the answer to the question I mentioned above helped you please up vote that answer. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to, but I can't see any up arrows next to your post. Perhaps I don't have the privilege to do so as of yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, are you using a linux operating system with LXDE desktop on its own or are you using Lubuntu, which is a version of Ubuntu with LXDE desktop? The latest seems a more simpler choice for users who come from Windows, but Lubuntu 14.04.1 has already been released.

I am not an expert, but if the method in the link of the first reply did not work, it might be a screen resolution problem and the most voted answer in this topic might solve the problem:
[How do I safely change grub2 screen resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54067/how-do-i-safely-change-grub2-screen-resolution)

You should be aware that a system called Grub is loaded before Linux and then you can prevent Linux from being loaded in order to change its loading way.

And you can also open a text terminal when Linux has finished loading. In a terminal you can run command to change the screen resolution and edit files to vary the default screen resolution. Press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open to a text terminal and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to go back to the usual graphic terminal.

That most voted answer describe how to change the screen resolution before Linux starts being loaded and a reply by @user01 to this most voted tells how to do the same after Linux has finished loading.

Anyway I do not know if this can be a screen resolution problem, but I wanted to note the information about terminals and grub and suggest this other option.

You can download Lubuntu 14.04.1 from [www.lubuntu.net](http://www.lubuntu.net).

Goodbye

Comment: Your correction are welcome as they have improved my poor message, but I am not sure that Lubuntu 14.04.1 has been released. Although lsb_release command shows that my computer is running Ubuntu 14.04.1, the official website of Lubuntu does not say anything about that.