# I'm trying to uninstall Ubuntu but there's some issues

Tags: dual-boot

I've installed it and my pc hangs a lot and screen fluctuate lot of times.. I'm not able to login to my Windows account (I've not uninstalled it) but if I start or restart the system Ubuntu is booted.. I'm not even able to open browser and look up for solutions

Comment: see if [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178614/cant-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu) helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Uninstall Ubuntu Completely, please follow the steps given [here. 
**How To Safely Uninstall Ubuntu From A Windows Dual-Boot PC**](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/)

If you want to make grub appear with options to boot into any Installed OS, then first try `sudo update-grub` in your terminal.

[This](http://cant-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu) link provides complete details on [cant-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178614/cant-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu).

There might one more cause, grub time set to zero. To set it follow : [How do I set the grub timeout and the grub default boot entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry)